# Как поставить картинки

Tags: html, css

Как поставить картинки в таком положении сверху экрана (CSS)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

советую посмотреть display flex css

```css
.thirdImage img{
  margin: auto;
 display: block
 
  
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  margin: auto
}
.firstImage{
   margin: auto
}
.secondImage{
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstImage">
     <img src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/34/posts/28933/preview_image/angular-js.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="secondImage">
     <img src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/34/posts/28933/preview_image/angular-js.png" alt="">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdImage">
    <img src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/34/posts/28933/preview_image/angular-js.png" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: результат видно когда вы нажмете на кнопку ՛На всю страницу՛

Answer (score 0):

чтобы вставить изображение используй

```
<img src="путь к файлу">
```

в css просто ставишь нужные width и heigh
Например:

```
.style{
width: 1080;
heigh: 720;}
```

Ну и с помощью padding и margin позиционируешь элементы)